# javascript to insert image

Tags: javascript

I am currently building a site to be used for a digital menu display. I am having trouble getting a input field that user is prompted to change the picture in the page. the images will be hosted locally on the displays netbook not through the sites server (picture selections will change regularly). any ideas would be a great help
 bellow is the code i have so far:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Custom Entree</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
    }
#apIMG {
    position:absolute;

    top:50px;
    width:1080px;
    height:200px;
    z-index:2;
    text-align:right;
}

#apPDF {
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
}
#pdfscoop {
    height:1358px;
    width:1050px;

}


#PRC {
    position:absolute;
    height:120px;
    width:100%;
    top:1708px;
    font-family:BrushScriptStd;
    text-align:center;
    }

#price {
    height:120px;
    width:1080px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:BrushScriptStd;
    font-size:110px;
    color:#090;

    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var img = document.getElementById('logo').src='';
document.images.item(
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="apIMG"><a href="http://www.artisancateringandevents.com/Content_Pages/scoop_webMenu.html" target="_top"><img src="scoopTitle.png" height="130%" width="*" ></image></a></div>

<div id="apPDF">

<embed name="" id="logo" src="custom.pdf#scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="900px" height="900px" scrollbar="0" /><input name="" type="image" width="900" height="900" /></div>
<div id="PRC"><input type="text" id="price" border="0" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="price" border="0" /></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is.  Please state the desired result you are trying to achieve and what specific question you want help with.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like your question is that clear.  To replace an image's source, it's as simple as this:

```
var images = ['imageone.jpg','imagetwo.jpg'];    
var img    = document.getElementById('logo');
img.src    = images[0];
```

[EDIT:] Based on your last comment using file://, it looks like this is what you are after:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function callme() {
        document.getElementById('logo').src = document.getElementById('file').value;
    }
</script>
<img id='logo' src='' />
<input id='file' type='file' onchange='callme()' value='' />
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear. what i need is when the "logo" field is clicked it prompts the user to import a picture from the local computer and post it to that field.

Comment: So, flow is: user clicks logo > upload form pops up > user uploads image to something like an iframe, which uploads in the background and prompts the main window when complete > the main page is updated with the uploaded image.  That is what you are aiming at?

Comment: this almost does it properly:   <script type="text/javascript">
function image(){
var img1 = window.location='file:\\';
document.getElementById('logo') = img1;
}
</script>

Comment: that works great but it keeps giving me file:///C:/Users/muskratjc/Desktop/C:/fakepath/Chef's%20Line.jpg as the source

Comment: thank you for all of your help. ive been stuck on this for a while now